# FHIR visualizer tool

Tags: data-visualization, offline

I work with [FHIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Healthcare_Interoperability_Resources) files, which are big and complex JSON files used in healthcare. I'd like to understand what I'm working with, so it would be super nice to somehow visualize the files locally.

There seems to be a lot of parsers etc, and tools connecting to servers to download and upload FHIRs and convert them, but I'd just need to visualize what I already have... IntelliJ plugin would have been optimal but there doesn't seem to be such a thing. Even a command line tool would be better than nothing.

Working on linux, but interested on tools for other platforms, too.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about: https://fhirblog.com/2019/06/01/fhir-bundle-visualizer/ , extracting data (I assume these can be explored in more detail):

[image]

and visualizing the internal structure:

[image]

This example is a web-based tool, but my FHIRs are private data, so I would need a local tool.

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by "visualize". Some example may be helpful

Comment: @RomeoNinov sure. Added an example.

Comment: my understanding is this visualization is based on several documents, not one JSON file. And display kind of relation between them. In such case maybe you need to search for something like graph databases where such relations are BAU

Comment: @RomeoNinov no, what is seen in images is contents of one json FHIR. One FHIR can contain several messages and it will contain hierarchical data in itself. The files can be very complex, having JSON file with weight >1M is not unheard of.